# google cloud build failed missing dependencies

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

[build log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1npvnbH85GrFXR8F0HkNEKzTOgU3md8Ox/view?usp=sharing)

```
Step #2 - "build": Running "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! code EUSAGE
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! 
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

[github project](https://github.com/yanivavraham1/cuponim)

I'm trying using Google Cloud Service to deploy `gcloud app deploy` my experss app for my website but when deploy the build fail

Installations:

`node.js 18.17.0`

`gcloud: Google Cloud SDK 440.0.0 bq 2.0.94 core 2023.07.21 gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0 gsutil 5.25`

I have tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules directory run npm install and npm ci and it didn't change the result. when running node app.js on my pc its apper to work in http://localhost:3000/stores/store1

also I tried using Firebase Cloud Functions and got the same result (missing dependencies)

Comment: Try specifying Node 18.16.1 in package.json.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Change the line `"node": "18.17.0"` in package.json.

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: Did you repeat `npm install`? Changing the Node version requires resetting up your project.

Comment: sorry. Just did but still same result

Comment: I uploaded my project to Github repository :)

Comment: You are not doing something correctly if you are getting the same result. The error message would have changed. However, this is very basic Node.js stuff. Perhaps read some documentation on how to set up a project.